# Clone rows except one attribute

Tags: oracle

Say I have that kind of a table

```
  COMMAND     XCODE     YCODE
1.INPUT       1000      1001
2.INPUT       2000      2001
3.INPUT       3000      3001
4.INPUT       4000      4001
```

And I want to insert exact same rows with one difference , as follows

```
  COMMAND      XCODE     YCODE
1.INPUT        1000      1001
2.INPUT        2000      2001
3.INPUT        3000      3001
4.INPUT        4000      4001
5.OUTPUT       1000      1001
6.OUTPUT       2000      2001
7.OUTPUT       3000      3001
8.OUTPUT       4000      4001
```

I want only one query that will handle all insertions at once. It could be hundreds of lines. I just gave an example of 4 rows..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use INSERT INTO...SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO table (COMMAND, XCODE, YCODE)
SELECT ('OUTPUT', XCODE, YCODE)
FROM table;
```

I've never used Oracle but hopefully this is standard enough to work.